# Python: ModuleNotFoundError encountered when importing modules from nested folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

So, I encountered a `ModuleNotFoundError` when trying to import a module in a subpackage that imports another subpackage under its directory (so it's a subsubpackage to the main directory). I have put empty `__init__.py` files under both the subdirectory and subsubdirectory. The code was run in Python 3.9.7.

Here's what the structure looks like:

```
|- main.py
|- subpackage/
   |- __init__.py
   |- submod.py
   |- subsubpackage/
      |- __init__.py
      |_ subsubmod.py
```

**The code**

In `main.py`, I have:

```
from subpackage import submod

def main():
    x = submod.test_func(3)
    print(x)

if __name__ == 'main':
    main()
```

and in `submod.py`, I want to import `subsubmod.py` under `subsubpackage/`, so I have:

```
from subsubpackage import subsubmod

def test_func(a):
    return subsubmod.addone(a)
```

and finally, in `subsubmod.py`:

```
def addone(x):
    return x+1
```

**The error message:**

Now if I run `main.py`, I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/anonymous/test/main.py", line 1, in 
<module>
from subpackage import submod

File "/Users/anonymous/test/subpackage/submod.py", 
line 1, in <module>
from subsubpackage import subsubmod

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subsubpackage'
```

**My question and confusion**

I'm not sure what I have done wrong. I realized that `submod.py` can be run separately, so it seems that the issue occurs when the `import` goes down more than one subdirectory? I wonder if there's a way around this issue, or should I just use a different structure to organize my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a dot before the package name worked for me.

```py
from .subsubpackage import subsubmod
```

Looks like when you are in a package if you don't use relative import it will look for your packages somewhere else.

You can find more information here:
[Python documents about import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)
[StackOverflow question about relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72852)

Answer (score 0):

This question keeps showing up on Stack Overflow and I can understand why. So today I took the time to create a nested project with 1 top module and 2 nested sub modules both with classes in them. And another class was also created in the top module folder. This is also considered a module by python. But it's in the same folder as the top module.

The skeleton nested module project is now live on Github at:

[HdlHelpers Nested Modules Skeleton Project](https://github.com/doswellf/HdlHelpers)